Used space does not match after fstrim
We have a Ubuntu-based systems (Ubuntu Jammy, no GUI, Radxa Rock 4B+ board) with SSD disk Samsung EVO 1TB. Filesystem is ext4. Whole system occupies about 4.5 GB. Backup image is created and it has about 5 GB. When this backup image is copied to new devices, the root partition is resized to match the whole disk size using resizepart/resize2fs.
After the resize, "df" command reports the correct used space which (approximately) matches the used space reported by "du /" command. It is about 5 GB. But after a short time, the used space reported by "df" command increases to 19 GB although nothing is actually written to the disk.
$ df -h
/dev/nvme0n1p3       932G   19G  876G   3% /

$ sudo du -h -d0  /
4,5G    /

My question is why? And how to reclaim this space back?
The common answer I have found is to use "sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/nvme0n1p3" but this is not the case. This command influences the free space but not used space.
After some experiments, I have found that my problem is somehow related to "fstrim" which is done in the background. Calling this command manually on the clean system immediately increases the used space to 19 GB.
I also noticed that this reported used space is actually not used at all because writing anything (of course, below this size) to the disk does not increase this used space. The problem is that creating a new backup image now results in 19 GB image although it contains only 5 GB of data.

I added some details to the original post. Although the system is Ubuntu Jammy, it happens on Debian Bookworm too. CLI version is used, no GUI. Nothing is done after the backup image is "installed" to the new device, it just runs and used space reported by "df" increases to 19 GB after fstrim.

I have the opposite situation, where du reports more used space than df (also when mounted drives are excluded). Generally, I would rely more on df, but I can't explain why space reported with df can vary that much.
